# Building multiple javascript projects

Tags: javascript, webpack, gruntjs

I have a web application that contains several javascript projects which are contained in separate sub-folders. Each project uses either gulp, grunt or webpack for their build system.

The projects are pretty fragmented at the moment and I'd like to move towards a unified way of building and testing all javascript projects using a single command at the top level directory.

What's the best approach for this? Should I start with using grunt at the top and reference each sub project? Or should I go with something like https://github.com/lerna/lerna?

Comment: refer to this repository  https://github.com/shridharkaushik29/laravel-angular, it contains webpack config for multiple projects and also watch and build commands are included in package.json, however it's a laravel project but, you'll find the information needed for webpack there